# footer CSS using fixed or absolute

Tags: html, css

I want my footer to stick at the bottom, I use below CSS:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
}
```

I also tried `absolute` for `position`. It worked visually, but it did not quite works in mobile. When user try to fire their keyboard, the footer will come up, it should not overlay the keyboard.

Comment: When keyboard opens in mobile the viewport height will be reduced. The only way is, You have to hide and show the footer while focusing and blur inputs.

Comment: @HarishKommuri are u sure? I don't see other website has that problem

Comment: Which site you see like that? You could dig in their codes.

Comment: @ata stackoverflow, the footer isn't `fixed`

Comment: When you use `position:fixed` the element stick on the viewport. Stackoverflow doesn't use `fixed`, if your footer doesn't stick at the bottom of the page, probably something is wrong in HTML. Could you make a fiddle of your page?

Comment: @ata because I don't have long content, if I don't make it fixed to the bottom, my footer is not like a footer.

Answer (score 0):

If it overlay the keyboard, maybe you shoud play a bit with:

```
z-index
```

Comment: The keyboard is a browser's native feature. `z-index` in your code won't have any effect on it.

Comment: I meant z-index on the footer because it overlay the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Co you use HTML5 semantics? I mean `<footer>`. Look at this simple example:

```css
footer {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
  </header>

  <footer>
    <h1>BYE</h1>
  </footer>
</body>
```

`<footer>` should automatically stick to the bottom of the page.